# upsert operation in netsuite using java code

Tags: java, http, netsuite

I am new to netsuite.I need to do a upsert opertaion using netsuite in my implemenation class. I am trying to pass my upsertrequest object to netsuite using upsert operation method(generated by using netsuite wsdl). I need to pass the object to the netsuite using my credentials and password.

I have imported netsuite login class loginrequest,loginresponse in my implementation to do the login using my credentials,

how do i need to do the login by passing my credentials to netsuite using java code? whether do i need to use http client or SOAP to send the upsertrequest object and credentials to do login?

eg:
emailid: test@gmail.com
password:test
account_id: 123

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the sample applications provided by Netsuite?  They are a very useful tool and probably will help you answer your question.  You can find them here: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml

From What I know: (I normally use php to interact with Netsuite, so my knowledge is limited, but I have used java a few times)
You will need to **use SOAP** to upsert the object.  Once you have logged in by creating a new NsClientObject, you simply call the appropriate method on the create object.  This will automatically take care of authentication.

```
ns = new NSClient();//assumes you have set your credentials in nsclient.properties in the root of the project
ns.callRelevantMethod();
```

If you are interested in php code, there are plenty of examples on my blog ([Netsuite sample code](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/tag/netsuite/))

Also http://usergroup.netsuite.com is a forum where you can see lots of sample code and netsuite developers will often post responses to inquires.  You may want to try that too.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Could you provide an example how to send using soap. it will be helpful for me. waiting for your reply.

Comment: Have you taken a look at that first link.  The sample code contains a complete java example of updating a netsuite record.  It should provide you with the classes you need as well.  https://system.netsuite.com/download/NSJavaClientCRM2012-1.zip

Comment: This post on the user group also contains a good java example of logging in: https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/showthread.php?t=23156&highlight=login+java
It requires registration, but the registration is free.